# Почему в sftp не я не могу получить разрешение на запись и как мне сделать, чтобы записывалось?

Tags: linux, sftp

Чего я хочу добиться:
Иметь пользователя, который при подключении через sftp он сразу попадал в разрешённую ему директорию и мог делать всё что угодно, однако за пределы той директории не выходил (даже не видел содержимое тех директорий). Нужно чтобы это всё работало без mount и без ln
Вот какие команды я делаю:

```
addgroup –-system sftpusers
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#там я пишу
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftpusers
ChrootDirectory %h
ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0007
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no

#далее продолжаем
useradd -d /var/www/mysite.com -s /bin/false -g sftpusers user4 
passwd user4

mkdir /var/www
mkdir /var/www/mysite.com

find /var/www/mysite.com -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
find /var/www/mysite.com -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
chown -R user4:sftpusers /var/www/mysite.com;
chmod 755 /var/www/mysite.com;
chown root:root /var/www/mysite.com;

systemctl restart sshd
```

После всех этих команд пользователь при подключении попадает в папку /var/www/mysite.com , но он не может ничего там делать. Частично я догадываюсь, что причина в команде chown root:root /var/www/mysite.com; , однако без неё пользователь вообще не может подключиться к файловой системе. Ошибка: FATAL ERROR: Network error: Software caused connection abort

Подскажите, что нужно сделать, чтобы всё заработало и я могла из пользователя user4 править папку mysite.com?

p.s. за основу моих команд бралась вот эта статья: https://wiki.dieg.info/sftp

Comment: Это один из квирков `sftp`/`openssh`/`chroot` связанных с тем, что по причинам безопасности `openssh` откажется делать `chroot` в каталог, которым владеет не `root`... поэтому пользователю `sftp` невозможно предоставить доступ к корневому каталогу, в который он был за'`chroot`'ен... самое постое — создать внутри ещё один каталог и дать право писать в него: `mkdir -p /var/www/mysite.com/mysite.com; chown -R user4:sftpusers !$`